# Display Word and Excel file on Web Page in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to show word and excel file using **iframe** tag and also tried with **embed** tag but in both case when web page is loading all files are downloading.

I also tried **Google docs viewer** in **iframe** tag but its support was closed by **Google**.
Below code I tried before:

```
<iframe height='500' width='500' src='https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=Sampledoc.docx'></iframe>
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: You can't. That viewer displays *the end user's Google Docs documents* specified by a URL to the document itself. It's not just an IFRAME and `embed`. Even if the viewer didn't restrict access (as it should), the URL has to point to an actual document accessible by **Google** servers.

Comment: Thank you @PanagiotisKanavos
I tried Both but iframe and embed tag downloading files which we given in 'src' (word and excel file)

Comment: see this link https://blog.groupdocs.com/2019/11/21/document-viewer-in-asp-net-core-mvc-csharp/

Comment: @meysamasadi that essentially says "Impossible, unless you use our product and add our viewer component in your application"

Comment: @ArpitPatel I just said neither approach could ever work. Browsers display only a few file formats. IE is the only browser that ever displayed Word documents, only if Word itself was installed. When you click on a document in GMail or Outlook, the web app itself launches *its own viewer component* to display the document. For very obvious security reasons, none of them will accept arbitrary URLs

Comment: @ArpitPatel even if a viewer does allow any URL, it has to be an absolute URL to a publicly available document. The viewer is going to *download* that document, render it into HTML and display the HTML in the browser. If you want to display local documents you'll have to add a viewer component to your application. Most of them aren't free though